# How to install "Docker 1.12.0 RC" on Ubuntu?

Tags: server, docker

I want to use the newest `Docker 1.12.0 RC` on my `Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS`, while following this official [tutorial](https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/linux/ubuntulinux/), I can only install `Docker 1.11.2`:

```
# docker version
Client:
 Version:      1.11.2
 API version:  1.23
 Go version:   go1.5.4
 Git commit:   b9f10c9
 Built:        Wed Jun  1 22:00:43 2016
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64

Server:
 Version:      1.11.2
 API version:  1.23
 Go version:   go1.5.4
 Git commit:   b9f10c9
 Built:        Wed Jun  1 22:00:43 2016
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
```

How to install `Docker 1.12.0 RC` on `Ubuntu`?

Answer (score 1):

You can use their install script:

```
sudo -s
curl -fsSL https://test.docker.com/ | sh
```